# can I combine `fs.stat` & `fs.readFile` into a single IO operation that is more efficient?

Tags: node.js, fs

In node.js - is there a way to access the `stats` on a file on the filesystem, as well as its contents, without having to access the file twice from the filesystem. I have the following, but instinct tells me this should could be simplified and optimised... just not sure how.

Will opening a file pointer using `fs.open` and performing `fs.read` and `fs.fstat` on the `fd` returned by the callback be any *more efficient* ?

How will I do that?

For context, I currently have the following in a router (using [fastify](https://www.fastify.io)):

```
const pathstring = path.resolve(__dirname, `./schema/${req.params.schemaName}.json`)
fs.stat(pathstring, (err, stats) => {
  if (err) return reply.send(err)
  fs.readFile(pathstring, {encoding: 'utf8'}, (err, file) => {
    if (err) return reply.send(err)
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(file)
      reply.header('last-modified', stats.mtime)
      .send(json)
    } catch (err) {
      reply.send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `stat` does not access the file, only the table entry where the filesystem stores meta data. Those operations are different OS system calls, even if you write code in C you will have to use different system calls. stat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29 -- Whenever you are in doubt about "optimizations": **Test it!** Write a little performance test reflecting your particular situation and setup. Don't theorize about such marginal things. Theory about performance only works for more or less obvious stuff. If your `stat` is meant to check existence, DON'T - just read.

Comment: @Mörre - agree, writing a performance test would be the way to reach a conclusion. Still wondering what I would test my approach above against (i.e. my original question remains - is there a way to rewrite this in a way that doesn't  acceess the filesystem twice?) Once I can establish a method, I can do things like performance tests. I'm not checking existence with `stat` - I'm getting modified date to pass on to the client.

Comment: _"is there a way to rewrite this in a way that doesn't acceess the filesystem twice"_ -- I believe I actually answered that question? :-)